# Sprintf not working with dragon12-light board(C)

Tags: c, embedded, printf, 68hc12

I'm trying to program a Dragon12-Light board to display information to a PC through Cool Term terminal software, however I can't seem to get the sprintf function to work properly.  The goal is to send information from the temperature sensor and light sensor to the terminal, but I've even tried it with dummy values and it's not operating properly.  Here's the code:

```
void main(void) {
  PLL_init();        // set system clock frequency to 24 MHz 
  DDRB  = 0xff;       // Port B is output
  DDRJ  = 0xff;       // Port J is output
  DDRP  = 0xff;       // Port P is output
  PTJ = 0x00;         // enable LED
  PTP = 0x00;         // enable all 7-segment displays
  PORTB   = 0x55;     // turn on every other led and segment on 7-seg displays
  initSCI0();


  for(;;) {

  unsigned char pot = '1';
  unsigned char pot_out;
  unsigned char temperature;
  unsigned char light;
  unsigned char receive;
  char buffer[50];
  int test = 10;

  sprintf(buffer, "test = %d", test);

  receive = SCI0_receiveByte();

  if(receive == '1'){


  SCI0_transmitString(buffer);

  }


  } /* wait forever */
}
```

I've verified that all functions operate properly, and if  I put a char array with a defined value into the transmit string function, it will display properly on the terminal when '1' is pressed on the keyboard, but the sprintf command doesn't seem to be writing anything to the array.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does execution survive the call to sprintf() or does it run away in some sort of crash or fault handler?  Is your receiver going to promptly display something that doesn't end with a newline or carriage return?  What happens if you take out the receive check on which the transmission is conditional?

Comment: Execution survives and it compiles properly with no crashes.  It would still show properly without a newline character, it would just show repeatedly on the same line.  Nothing is shown on the terminal screen when there is no transmission conditional.

Comment: Specs on your kit say it has a debug monitor, you should be able to follow this and see what happens.

Comment: The debug monitor is showing a bunch of random values for the buffer char array I'm attempting to use sprintf with.  Value [0] = -69, [1] = -44, [2] = 0, [3] = 0... they all just appear to be random numbers.

Comment: Firs you probably want those in hex, but then as non-printable values with a zero far too early, these are presumably the values before the call - since it's a stack variable the memory is likely to have been used before.

Comment: Assuming it is not as simple as having forgotten to include stdio.h, nobody will be able to reproduce the bug. Which compiler are you using? Is this code running on top of the horrible bootloader "dbug12" or did you actually flash it yourself with a BDM? Is this code built as a flash project or some nonsense "RAM project"?

Comment: Oh! And what's the memory model? You can get really weird results if the PPAGE of the HCS12 is not set to the correct bank. Suppose for example that it reads address 0x8000 instead of address 0x388000. Various versions of various HCS12 compilers struggled with bugs related to PPAGE. Unless you really need a ton of program flash, I would advise to stay clear of the banked memory model.